# How long can fox baits be harmful for my dog?

Tags: dogs, health, poison

My neighbors whippet recently died from going into the bush when there were fox baits. The councils do warn that they are laying baits. (I also had a whippet that died from being baited on our common property here, but that's a separate story)

The local councils here use [Foxoff®](http://www.animalcontrol.com.au/fox-bait1.htm) poison baits (containing 1080). Is this kind of bait something that becomes safe after a certain time or do they all need to be eaten?

It concerns me, as even though the council gives a time period that is not safe, after my neighbor's dog died, I've been a bit worried about baits being left in the bushland.

Also, does anyone know how this kills the dog, is it a painful way to die? I haven't been able to ask my neighbor exactly what happened as she is too distressed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the link in your question "A single FOXOFF® bait is lethal to the largest fox."

A fox is closely related to domestic dogs.  They are both part of [the family Canidae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canidae).  They are shelf stable meaning that they remain potent for a long time.  For safety sake I would not permit any animal to eat one ever no matter how long it has been there.  Just because it may have past its expiration date does not mean that it is no longer poisonous just that the manufacturer is not guaranteeing its effectiveness.  It is a type of poison that is going to be very effective against most dogs so you are best to avoid them, and not let your dog root around in gardens where you are not sure if the baits exist.